How we can apply a pure function for dot and prime
I want to apply a pure function. If Y[t,r]
How can I replace the derivative of Y with respect to t, OvertDot[Y], and the derivative with respect to r is Y^prime in general. Thanks in anticipation.

Please add the Mathematic code for your function so that people can copy and test your code without retyping it.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

Use Format
Format[Y[_, _]] := Y

Format[Derivative[n_, 0][Y][_, _]] := OverDot[Y, n];

Format[Derivative[0, n_][Y][_, _]] := Y^Row[ConstantArray["'", n]];

Format[Derivative[n_, m_][Y][_, _]] := 
  OverDot[Y, n]^Row[ConstantArray["'", m]];

Flatten[Table[D[Y[t, r], {t, n}, {r, m}], {n, 0, 3}, {m, 0, 3}], 1]



I want to pay special thanks to my professor, who give me this beautiful idea... It works with colors, with different styles, with different manners as I want, and as any type of function which I wants to use ... thanks a lot.
